# Set same key order as json has ios

Tags: ios, iphone, object, nsmutabledictionary

What i want is to maintain JSON key order. I'm getting JSON from server and i convert it into `NSMutableDictionary` but it change its order, but it should be in same order that JSON has. and if i change key order in server that is effect to application.

Here is code that i convert JSON to `NSMutableDictionary` :

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datas
  options:0 error:nil];
```

Here is json that comes from server :

```
{
  "data": {
      "Vehicle body/inside vehicle": [

      ],
      "Tranmission": [

      ],
      "Brakes": [

      ],
      "Steering": [

      ],
      "Engine checks/under bonnet": [

      ]
    },
}
```

but after convert it to dictionary it changes it order in ascending order.

Comment: Due to the fact that `NSDictionary` is implemented as hash map, it does not have a specific order. There is no going around this.

Comment: A dictionary is an unordered collection type. I wrote this comment in another question just one hour ago: *If a certain order is mandatory a dictionary is the wrong collection type.*

Comment: yes i added in array alos. but it is same.

Comment: @KaviPatel your dict always have the same keys? or can be any new keys in it?

Comment: Yes there is diff key init.

Answer (score 0):

Send json data here

```
    var data: String()
    func convertToDictionary(text:String)-> Any?{
     if let data = text.data(using: .utf8){
        do{
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsondata, options: []) as? Any
        } catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}


     if let jsonlist = self.convertToDictionary (text: data) as? [AnyObject]{

       for i in jsonlist as! [[String: AnyObject]]{
          data = I["data"] as! String
            print(data)
            }
         }
```

I did it this way